# Properly Formed HTML as String in Div on .Net Web Form is Rendering Well Beyond Extremely Slow

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, iframe

I have evidently inadvertently created a beast that I would appreciate ideas on where to look for alternatives or how I might identify the problem. (This is a C# .Net 3.0 app.)

I have a master page that contains 4 textboxes.  When the user enters text in one of the text boxes it triggers a javascript call to refresh the search results page that is inside an IFrame on the master page.

When the search results page loads a call is made to a property '<%=results %>' which calls the search function.  The search function retrieves an XML string from the SQL Server database, loads it into an XmlDocument, and transforms the output with XLST into a stringWriter back to the property "results".

The XSLT output is a table with about 24 columns, javascript on the row click for highlighting a row, and some links on each row for going to a new screen to edit the selected record.

It works in a timely fashion up to 100 rows.  When it reaches 200 table rows the lag time becomes noticable.  At 500 rows it takes about 12 - 15 seconds to render, and then at 1000 rows it takes 90 seconds.  There are 3000 records possible and the user would like to be able to have an option to return all rows for sorting, analyzing, and possibly exporting; so, I need a better mouse trap.

The delay is entirely in the browser rendering with Internet Explorer 8.0.  With Google Chrome it takes approximately 7 seconds for 1000 rows.  Also, I have used additional test code to write the html output from the xslt transform to a file to ensure the output is well formed and there are no problems noted.  I have navigated to the saved file on my local machine and with the 1000 rows in a fresh browser window and it takes approximately 5 seconds to load into the browser; so, I am really at a loss as to why it takes 90 seconds to load directly into the web form in the IFrame.

Does anyone have a clue what might be happening and how to resolve the problem(s)?  Is there a better way to crack this nut?  Would it be any better if I saved the XSLT output to a file and loaded that into the IFrame?  Or maybe I should scrap the xslt and just use a response.Write loop?

Comment: Can you add your code? It's a little hard to guess this way.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time using this forum.  Do I just paste it into the comments area?

Comment: Are you sure that the transformation takes 90 seconds? Off topic: events in EmacScript should be properly handle by event capture and event bubble mechanism, that way you need only to register one element in common ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you killed the problem with an old, unoptimized solution.

First of all, I would point to the fact of *why to use an iframe approach if AJAX is its modern, supported and optimal solution?*.

Server-processing should be done with some service - maybe a Windows Communication Foundation one with an HTTP binding and hosted in Internet Information Services - and it can use a JSON data contract serializer. That's returned data is going to be reduced and this is a very light-weight communication, dramatically-incresing network performance/usage.

Working with JSON makes like easier. You'll have your results as JavaScript objects, so translating JSON result into run-time-created DOM elements is easy: just iterate results and use jQuery in order to quickly create table rows (or you can switch to ASP.NET 4.0 and take advantage of client-side data binding (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc972638.aspx) and make it even easier (I don't know if you can do that, it's just a suggestion!!).

Calling WCF JSON-enabled service with jQuery or any other JavaScript client API is easy and it'll save you development time and it'd incredibly increase your application performance and responsiveness.

Here you've an ASP.NET 3.5 example of how to work with WCF, JSON and client-side service calls. 
http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/JSON-EnabledWCFServicesInASPNET35.aspx

Comment: Before going down this road I had built a WCF to provide JSON data and ran into the max limit for data packets such that I would have to build a loop to recieve the data in smaller chunks until end.  I also tried to use a grid view in the web form but it also was very slow in rendering the data.  I came up with my solution because I thought it might be easier to manage over time with the ability to adjust the XML output from the SQL query and the XSLT file both in about 5 minutes and very little deployment effort--no recompile necessary.I would love to do a true AJAX solution

Comment: But I believe your problem is you want to get ALL data without paging. In a "true AJAX solution" you'd never take 5000 records from the store and transport to the client, you would do it with paging, which is the optimal and right solution for data navigation like one in a grid view. What do you think?